# You don't have Add and Customize Pages permissions

Tags: 2013, development, web-part, permissions, design

Currently when contributor users inside our enterprise wiki 2013 try to add a new web part to a wiki page, they will get the following error:-

> A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or
>   imported. You don't have Add and Customize Pages permissions required
>   to perform this action.

I read that I can grant them the following:-

[image]

But it seems that this is too much permission in my case, because it will allow users to edit the web site using an editor. **So is there a permission  level which only allow contributor users to add web parts to the page without any extra permissions** ?

Thanks

Comment: You must have permissions to edit a page to be able to add Webparts on it

Comment: @RobertLindgren yes i know that. but currently users with Contributor permission level are not able to add web parts. and to enable them to add web parts i have to assign them the permission to modify the web site using an editor. so my question if there is a way to allow Contributor users to add web parts , without going too much into the ability to modify the web site using editor tools...

Comment: as currently the only avilable permission level is the one which i highlight in my original question. which will allow them to do extra work beyond adding web parts..